Cross Compile C Using Clang - can't find header files
I'm trying to do cross compile using Apple MacOs built-in Clang. My compile machine is arm64, MacOs; the target machine is x86_64, Ubuntu.
Below is some other info:

clang version (used two versions):

Before:
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

After:
clang --version
Homebrew clang version 18.1.8
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin


llvm install status:

brew info llvm
==> llvm: stable 18.1.8 (bottled), HEAD [keg-only]
Next-gen compiler infrastructure
https://llvm.org/
Installed
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/18.1.8 (7,722 files, 1.8GB)
  Poured from bottle using the formulae.brew.sh API on 2024-07-03 at 15:53:47
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/l/llvm.rb
License: Apache-2.0 with LLVM-exception
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✔, ninja ✘, swig ✘
Required: python@3.12 ✔, xz ✔, z3 ✔, zstd ✔


CMAKE file

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.5...3.9)

project(xxx)

add_executable(clientDemo clientDemo.c cJSON.c rgvMovement.c)
add_executable(serverDemo serverDemo.c cJSON.c)


toolchain file

# target machine architecture
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR x86_64)

set(triple arm-linux-gnueabihf)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET ${triple})

# I copied include files from the target machine to my compile machine
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT /Users/fred_zhang/Documents/x86_64_include)

# Without this flag, CMake is unable to pass the test compilation check
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)

# these variables tell CMake to avoid using any binary it finds in 
# the sysroot, while picking headers and libraries exclusively from it 
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)


build script

#!/bin/bash
curDir=`pwd`
buildDir="$curDir/build"

mkdir -p build
cd $buildDir

cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=./toolchain.cmake ../.
make -j8

mkdir -p output
mv clientDemo ./output
mv serverDemo ./output

echo "[Build] Finished building the project."

However, the compilation still has errors. It still can't find the header files which I already copied the x86_64-version header files to my local machine and set the sysroot to it.
fatal error: 'string.h' file not found #include <string.h>
Now I copied /usr/include and /usr/lib from target machine to my compile machine. And I wrote a helloWorld.c and tried to invoke clang manually with
clang --target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --sysroot=/Users/fred_zhang/Documents/x86_64_include -fuse-ld=lld -stdlib=libc++ -o helloWorld helloWorld.c -lz --verbose,
but had
clang: error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=lld'
error output. When I tried to get rid of -fuse-ld=lld, I got
stdlib.h:26:10: fatal error: 'bits/libc-header-start.h' file not found
error output.
Any suggestion? I am really lost. I researched online but got nothing really useful.

Put your app and cmake aside, and try cross-building a hello world program with a single manual invocation of clang.

Coping /include is not enough, you must copy / (with /usr/include, /usr/lib at least). and specify the path to that /.

Now I copied /usr/include and /usr/lib from target machine to my compile machine. And I wrote a helloWorld.c and tried to invoke clang manually with clang --target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --sysroot=/Users/fred_zhang/Documents/x86_64_include -fuse-ld=lld -stdlib=libc++ -o helloWorld helloWorld.c -lz --verbose, but had clang: error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=lld' error output. When I tried to get rid of -fuse-ld=lld, I got stdlib.h:26:10: fatal error: 'bits/libc-header-start.h' file not found error output.

What are the contents of x86_64_include? I also vaguely remember something about Apple Clang having problems with cross-compilation, which the normal Clang (even on Mac) didn't.

/x86_64_include has all the .h files I copied from the target machine. For example, it already has string.h in x86_64 architecture, but when I compile it, it still says it cannot find string.h. I tried both Apple Clang and Homebrew Clang. The latter one is good with -fuse-ld=lld arg, but still has the error output stdlib.h:26:10: fatal error: 'bits/libc-header-start.h' file not found #include <bits/libc-header-start.h>

As I said (maybe not very clearly), the path you give to --sysroot corresponds to / on the target system. So that path must contain usr/include and usr/lib, not headers directly.

@HolyBlackCat Hi there, I think your advice worked! I make the sysroot path as you said, and the former error didn't show up again. Now, there is new error: ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lz; clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Did you copy the lib directory, and do you have libz.a or libz.so in there?

@HolyBlackCat Yes, I copied the lib dir, and there are lots of subdir in this lib dir. However, I used find command and didn't find neither libz.a nor libz.so.

Before copying, you should install zlib on the source linux system using its package manager.

@HolyBlackCat Ok, thanks a lot. I will try this when I have the access to the target machine.
